# Почему charindex быстрее like %pattern%?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Недавно обнаружил, что `charindex` отрабатывает раза в 3 быстрее при частичном поиске. Ума не приложу почему это так... Вроде, и там и там частичное совпадение. Так же не понимаю почему оптимизатор не преобразует `like` к charindex когда используются только % без других символов подстановки, как это делается если а `like` не задействованы %. Что за магия?

Comment: А что такое "звездочки". у ms sql есть какие то нестандартные символы подстановки (не вижу этого в документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179859(v=sql.120).aspx) ? wildcard у like обычно `%`. И да, like может быть медленнее просто потому, что у него значительно более сложный алгоритм с возвратами, ради поддержки этих самых подстановок. А то что они не используются в конкретном случае - от этого алгоритм то не меняется. Почему оптимизатор не меняет: не умеет, не научили, предложите эту идею разработчикам MS SQL

Comment: @Mike, да я оговоролися % имел ввиду.